# Unable to validate and upload multiple images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I managed to successfully upload one image, and validation and upload processes went fine, but since i have tried to upload multiple images, not validation nor upload work.

it is the **model** called "ProductImage" that represents the "image" object which is supposed to save in disk and database.

```
public class ProductImage
{
public int ID { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "File")]
[StringLength(100)]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string FileName { get; set; }
}
}
```

and its the **controller** of ProductImage that takes incoming files as "HttpPostedFileBase[] files " go through them, check for 1-null, and 2-file's length, and if they are true, check files with ValidateFile() to see if they are jpeg, png and ...and less than 2mb, if files are valid, then save files in disk and proceed to save files in database , otherwise it throws error messages.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        bool allValid = true;
        string inValidFiles = "";
        //check the user has entered a file
        if (files[0] != null)
        {
            //if the user has entered less than ten files
            if (files.Length <= 10)
            {
                //check they are all valid
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (!ValidateFile(file))
                    {
                        allValid = false;
                        inValidFiles += ", " + file.FileName;
                    }

                }
                //if they are all valid then try to save them to disk
                if (allValid)
                {
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SaveFileToDisk(file);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("FileName", "Sorry ,and error has occured saving the file to disk,please try again.");
                        }

                    }
                }
                //else add an error listing out the invalid files
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("FileName", "All files must be gif,png,jpeg or jpg and less than 2mb in size.The following files" + inValidFiles + "are not valid");
                }

            }
            //the user has entered more than 10 files
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("FileName", "Please only upload up to ten files at a time");
            }

        }
        //if the user has not entered a file return an error message
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("FileName", "Please choose a file");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool duplicates = false;
            bool otheDbError = false;
            string dublicatesFiles = "";
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                //try and save each file
                var productToAdd = new ProductImage { FileName = file.FileName };
                try
                {
                    db.ProductImages.Add(productToAdd);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                //if there is an exception check if it is caused by a duplicate file
                catch (DbUpdateException ex)
                {
                    SqlException innException = ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException;
                    if (innException != null && innException.Number == 2601)
                    {
                        dublicatesFiles += ", " + file.FileName;
                        duplicates = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        otheDbError = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //add a list of duplicate files to the error message
            if (duplicates)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("FileName", "All files uploaded except the files" + dublicatesFiles + "which already exist in the system." + "please delete them and try again if you wish to re-add them");
                return View();
            }
            else if (otheDbError)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("FileName","Sorry an error has occurred saving to the database ,please try again ");
                return View();
            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and these are the **helper methods** : ValidateFile() and SaveFileToDisk()

```
private bool ValidateFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
        string[] allowedFileTypes = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", "jpg" };
        if ((file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength < 2097152) && allowedFileTypes.Contains(FileExtension))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void SaveFileToDisk(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
        if (img.Width > 190)
        {
            img.Resize(190, img.Height);
        }

        img.Save(Constants.ProductImagePath + file.FileName);
        if (img.Width > 100)
        {
            img.Resize(100, img.Height);
        }

        img.Save(Constants.ProductThumbnailPath + file.FileName);
    }
}
```

}

and I also updated the "multiple" attribute in Upload.chtml page to allow updating of few files

```
 <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple="multiple" class="form-control"/>
```

Now it dosen't matter what  I do, either uploading the right or wrong files, instead of showing the error message or save it in databse or disk , it just excute the last line of code which is

```
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and back to index page , whats the problem?

Comment: When you run this through the debugger what does the `files` parameter contain? Is it a populated `HttpPostedFileBase[]`?

Comment: well, if I choose 5 images, it says, files ={httpPostedFileBase[5]} and it is populated like : [0]={HttpPostedFileWrapper}, [1]={HttpPostedFileWrapper} , [2]={HttpPostedFileWrapper} and so on ..

Comment: OK, so when you run the debugger and verified you have input, you can step through to find out which line is giving you an error or failing to produce an expected result.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out. part of problem that i couldn't see the error messages was due to forgetting to write return view() at the end of the code . but still i had problem with saving files on disk and the only thing that could resolve the problem was changing the browsers to Firefox , don't know why